# JAX-RS JAXB JSON Response not working ( MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException)

Tags: json, jaxb, jax-rs

I had been working for sometime to figure out how to create a JAX Restful Service... using the guide available here - [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html)

As explained in Section 2.3.2, I had added the below dependency in Maven -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.hms.rs.controller.MyApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and MyApp.java

```
public class MyApp extends Application{

     @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            return new HashSet<Class<?>>() {{
                // Add your resources.
            System.out.println("From the Myapp...");
                add(Patient.class);
                add(PatientController.class);

            // Add LoggingFilter.
                add(LoggingFilter.class);
            }};
        }
}
```

Patient.java -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Patient")
public class Patient {

    private String patientFName;
    private String patientLName;
    private int patientAge;
    private String patientSex;
    private String patientParentSpouse;
    private String patientQual;
    private String patientOccupation;
    private String patientComments;

    public Patient()
    {
    }

Setters and Getters....

}
```

PatientController.java -

```
@Path("/ManagePatient")
public class PatientController {
      @GET
  @Path("/getPatient")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Patient printPatient() {
      System.out.println("Hello.... from the PatientController");
      Patient ptnt = new Patient();
      ptnt.setPatientFName("FirstN");
      ptnt.setPatientLName("LName");
      ptnt.setPatientAge(30);
      ptnt.setPatientSex("M");
      ptnt.setPatientParentSpouse("ParentSpuse");
      ptnt.setPatientQual("engg");
      ptnt.setPatientOccupation("software");
      ptnt.setPatientComments("comments here");

      System.out.println("Patient = " + ptnt);

    //return ptnt.toString();
      return ptnt;
  }
```

When I try to access this via browser @ localhost:8080/HMS_Web/services/ManagePatient/getPatient

I am getting

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient, genericType=class com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient.
```

and I also see the below warning in the logs-

```
WARNING: A provider com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient will be ignored.
```

If Jersey 2.0 supports JAXB based xml or json support as mentioned @ section "8.1.1.2. JAXB based JSON support" in the Jersey guide, I am not sure why I am receiving the Provider errors.

Could any JAX-WS expert help me understand and also provide me direction on how to resolve this situation?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just add Genson to your classpath and everything should work. It would also automatically support jaxb annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are accessing the service via browser, so your PatientController will try to render response as html, I guess this is the reason for the

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient, genericType=class com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient.
```

try to comsume the service via jersey client api as following:

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/HMS_Web/services/ManagePatient/getPatient");

Patient patient = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(Patient.class);
```

for the warning:

```
WARNING: A provider com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider com.hms.app.ui.beans.Patient will be ignored.
```

I think you should remove:

```
add(Patient.class);
```

in your **MyApp**. Patient is just a POJO, it is neither a resource nor a provider.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had worded the question wrong with respect to using the browser and I am using cURL for retrieving xml or json... While retrieving xml - I am getting HTTP 500 response (which I am trying to find out why) and while retrieving json - I am getting MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json. Working on adding moxy for that. Thank you very much for the response.